# Problems displaying two seperate values from the same mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql table called custom_values where in the table exists two columns, One called "custome_field_id" and one called "value".

The "value" column holds two different values that I need to pull and display on my page. One value is an "order number" value and the other is a "date" value. The "custom_field_id" column shows a custom_field_id of 33 for the "Date" value and 237 for the "order" value

What I would like to do is structure my php query so that in one select statement, I can display both of these values.

for example end up with an $actual_date and $Order variable that I can use.

Here is my current select statement that at this moment retrieves the "order" value. But I need to show both... I tried using Alias in in my select statement but it didnt work for me...

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT custom_values.value, issues.subject, issue_statuses.name, 
                issues.due_date, issues.id as issuesid, 
                users.firstname, users.lastname 
                FROM redmine.issues join redmine.projects on issues.project_id=projects.id 
                left join redmine.users on issues.assigned_to_id=users.id 
                left join redmine.custom_values ON issues.id=custom_values.customized_id 
                left join issue_statuses on issues.status_id=issue_statuses.id 
                where projects.id='".$_SESSION['id']."' 
                and custom_values.custom_field_id=237 ORDER BY $order ASC");

$stmt->execute();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have two "values" in a column you need to refactor your database.

Comment: `and custom_values.custom_field_id IN (33, 237)`

Comment: How do you have 2 values in a single database column? Are you serializing them to json or something? Can you just add your table structure to the post?

Comment: Hi Andy, the database is part of an application called "Redmine", and unfortunately that is the way the application inserts information into that database table. Im trying to create a custom page that pulls and displays this information. I can see if I can add the table structure to the post.

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN custom_values...  WHERE custom_field_id = 237` is the same as `INNER JOIN custom_values`

Comment: Typically, you would join the custom_values table twice, once for each attribute. Give each instance of the custom_values table a different alias.

Comment: How long do it take this query to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT v_order.value my_order
     , v_date.value date
     , i.subject
     , s.name
     , i.due_date
     , i.id issuesid
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname 
  FROM issues i
  JOIN projects p
    ON p.id = i.project_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = i.assigned_to_id
  LEFT
  JOIN custom_values v_order 
    ON v_order.customized_id = i.id
   AND v_order.custom_field_id = 237 
  LEFT
  JOIN custom_values v_date 
    ON v_date.customized_id = i.id
   AND v_date.custom_field_id = 33
  LEFT 
  JOIN issue_statuses s
    ON s.id = i.status_id
 WHERE p.id = "_SESSION['id']" 
 ORDER 
    BY $order ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly advise to build this in Ruby as a Redmine plugin then. Dealing with the database at this level is error-prone; working with the CustomField and CustomValue classes in Redmine however, will do all the abstraction for you.

You could even use the Redmine API [1] to access the data using HTTP.

[1] http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

Answer (score 0):

If the following is right:
*In the same database, you have 2 columns first contains 2 different numbers in case of two different values in the second column; therefore you have 2 rows per item to pull out*

Please correct me if I missunderstood.

Try the following:

```
... AND ( custom_values.custom_field_id=value_1 OR custom_values.custom_field_id=value_2 ) ORDER ...
```